# How to send dictionaries to functions in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
    }

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
    }
```

## Write your code below!

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for key in food:
        total = total + food[key]
    return total
print compute_bill(prices)
```

I'm on Codeacademy.com and they haven't really explained how to send dictionaries to functions. Just lists. When I run this code, it'll print out what I want but then I get this error and can't proceed:

```
Oops, try again. compute_bill(['apple']) resulted in a TypeError: list
indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: `['apple']` is a list, hence the error complaining about indexing a list with a string. I don't see anywhere in your posted code that this appears.

Comment: I don't get any error when I run your code. You don't have `compute_bill(['apple'])` anywhere, so it doesn't make sense that that would be the error message. Are you sure this is the code you're running?

Comment: You're code works fine for me (Python 2.7), printing `10.5`.

Comment: To answer your general question, there is no difference between passing dictionaries and passing anything else (lists, integers, strings...) in Python.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is. This is the code I copied over.

Comment: I am guessing that something else in some sort of teaching module is taking this code, and trying to call `compute_bill` by passing it a list of foods. So maybe the issue is really that the requirement of the coding exercise is to compute a bill based on a list of foods, not a dictionary of foods/prices?

Answer (score 2):

User better variable names so you don't confuse yourself. You have a table of prices and you want to look up each item in your "shopping list" using that table:

```
price_table = prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
    }

# Write your code below!
def compute_bill(things_I_want_to_buy):
    total = 0
    for item in things_I_want_to_buy:
        total = total + price_table[item]
    return total
print compute_bill(['apple', 'pear'])
```

Comment: So how exactly does that fix the (already error-less) code given in the question???

Comment: Code that returns an unexpected result is just as wrong as code that raises an error :). If you read the question carefully you'll see the result the OP is trying to get.

Comment: The code returns the sum of the values in the `prices` dictionary. What's unexpected in that???

Comment: The OP wants the price of his cart, not he price of everything in the store.

Comment: Where is that written in OP's question? The only thing mentioned (and asked) is how to send a dictionary to a function. And that is already done correctly in the given code.

Comment: The OP asks about sending a dictionary to a function, but the specified error (with the additional code that produces it) makes it clear that he's really wanting to send a `list` to the function, and is mistakenly indexing the passed object instead of the price dictionary in the loop. This answer solves that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the coding exercise aside, the answer to the actual question is that you pass a dictionary to a function the same way you would a list, an integer, a string, a set, a tuple, or an object of your own defined type.

For example, say I have a function called `quack_show`, and I wrote it expecting to get a list of ducks and make them all quack:

```
def quack_show(duck_list):
    for duck in duck_list:
        duck.quack()
```

Someone could pass a list of ducks to the function, but there is no restriction that says anyone has to.

First, `duck_list` doesn't necessarily have to be a list of ducks, just any arbitrary objects that have a `quack()` method that I can call.

Second, `duck_list` doesn't have to be a list, just something that I can iterate over with `for duck in duck_list`. You can iterate over lists, sets, tuples, and even define your own objects that you can do this with. You can iterate over strings and you will get individual characters.

All that matters for the function is that you can in fact iterate, and all the objects in the container have a `quack()` method. One could even send this function a dictionary, provided that the dictionary keys were objects that can `quack()`.